# How does Rey know how to swim?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

We see her doing that in *The Last Jedi*. The mirror cave scene.

But she's been in Jakku since she was 6.

I can't find an answer (besides the ones provided by speculation, of course)

Comment: The force works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Municipal swimming pool?

Comment: The Force provides knowledge and guides the actions of Force-sensitive sapients.

Comment: Suspension of belief to assume that everyone in the SW galaxy just knows how to swim like an inherited life skill.

Comment: Perhaps she learned before she was 6?

Comment: Maybe because she's a *Sting-Rey* :p

Comment: You never been sand-swimming?

Comment: @Shreedhar - I honestly don't know whether to laugh or cry, but either way I take my (metaphorical) hat off to you.

Answer (score 16):

She doesn't swim. She falls into the water, flails around madly and eventually makes it to the edge, doggy-paddle style.

> She landed with a splash in a pool of water. Gasping, she paddled to
> an outcropping of stone. **She was lucky she didn’t drown. Swimming
> lessons had not been a priority on Jakku.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Official Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

and

> She fell into water, the cold like a knife in her lungs. **She
> struggled, surfaced, and gasped, eyes stinging from the salt, then
> hauled herself out onto the slick, flat stone.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ok. She didn't swim. But she didn't drown. How? 'Lucky' is not really an explanation, and that word belongs to her POV (free indirect speech). The official novelization describes what she did more objectively, but offers no explanation.

Comment: @Sunsetguy6776 - it says it right there. She "paddled'. You seem to be under the impression that anyone who cannot swim that falls into water will ***immediately sink to the bottom and drown***, but that simply isn't the case.

Comment: So, she was lucky. Ok.

Comment: @Sunsetguy6776 - If you're in water and you wiggle your arms and legs, motion will be accomplished, especially if you dog-crawl in the general direction of where you want to go. Note that she's very fit, so although she'll tend to sink (due to how lean she is), her arm and leg movements will propel her quite effectively.

Comment: Sure, but she could have drown. Those 'if' don't always present themselves, and 'very fit' people can die, and do. So, it was about a)luck or b)something else. In the film, to which the novels are subordinated when it comes to canon, we don't see enough to judge her abilities - what we see there is 100% compatible with swimming (Back in 2013/14, she could swim. There's concept art with Rey doing precisely that in scuba gear)

Comment: @Sunsetguy6776 - Ah well, I guess unexpectedly drowning your main character in the precise middle of a film series is a screenwriting no-no.

Comment: Of course. But maybe she already knew how to swim. That would rule out 'luck' as an explanation. From Vader's point of view, his son died (='drowned') before being born, but then he didn't. Or, Leia died from Kylo's perspective but then - 'Leia Poppins', that is Leia not 'drowning'- she didn't. So, maybe Rey drowned once before Jakku, but she didn't. What we see is ambiguous enough to sustain that reading (Her first lesson ends with water and child-like screaming coming from that hole) One of Abrams' favourite films is Ordinary People. This film has a troubled teenager and loss by drowning.